# AttributeError: module has no attribute while avoiding cyclic reference error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, attributeerror

I would like to create small app using M-VC pattern in python. I am using PyCharm and my folder structure looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQVaN.png).

To avoid problem with cyclic references I am using `import` not `from ... import`.

Program executes without error when my viewController.py looks like this:

```
import model
class ViewController:
    def initialize(self, mod):
        self.model = mod
```

Adding `model.Model` expression inside **initialize** method results with an error: `AttributeError: module 'model' has no attribute 'Model'` Why it works in model.py with `viewController.ViewController`? And what is wrong?

[new]viewController.py

```
import model
class ViewController:
    def initialize(self, mod:model.Model):
        self.model = mod
```

Back/__init_.py

```
import model
import viewController
mModel = model.Model()
mVC = viewController.ViewController()
mModel.initializeApp(mVC)
```

model.py

```
import viewController
class Model():
    def initializeApp(self, viewContr: viewController.ViewController):
        self.vc = viewContr
        self.vc.initialize(self)
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you think doing `import` would avoid cyclical references. The references are just as cyclical no matter how you import them.

Comment: Cyclic references still occur when using something like `import a` in b.py and `import b` in a.py. The way to avoid it is to import the module in a function scope.

Comment: Yes I understand it still occurs, however if I used ``` from ... import ``` I would get an error: "cannot import module..." because of the recursive call of that import in both files